# Convert Column Header to Top Row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert the Column header to Top row for the below data frame. I have done trials but it renaming not adding data. Can we able to do that without transposing the dataframe.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None}, 'A': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z'}, 'B': {0: '1', 1: '0', 2: '13'}})
print (df1)
df1.columns = range(df1.shape[1])
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert columns to `DataFrame`, transpose to one row DataFrame and add to original:

```
df = df1.columns.to_frame().T.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
      0  A   B
0     0  A   B
1  None  X   1
2  None  Y   0
3  None  Z  13
```

If necessary set `0` column to `None`:

```
df['0'] = None
print (df)
     0  A   B
0  None  A   B
1  None  X   1
2  None  Y   0
3  None  Z  13
```